# R: calculate volume of overlapping spheres

Tags: r, mesh, volume

I have a matrix of X, Y, Z coordinates. Each coordinate represents origin of sphere of radius R (same R for all coordinates). 
Now the challenge is to calculate volume occupied by the spheres.

I tried to approach it by:

1. plotting using `rgl.spheres`
2. saving mesh as STL
3. simplifying mesh ("decimate" in Blender)
4. checking the mesh volume in software such as MeshMixer

...but I realize there must be some less lame method out there :) 
Any ideas? (keep in mind number of coordinates is around 10 000)

thanks!

Comment: You mean the total occupied volume? It's not clear atm

Comment: yes, otherwise it will be just number of coordinates multiplied by sphere volume

Comment: [There is a closed form solution for this.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html) Enjoy the coding challenge :). The "computational" thing to do is to estimate the convex hull of the shape with a 3d-Polyaedrons.

Comment: 'hypervolume' package seems relevant